# UIImagePickerController with 3 Buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 3 buttons that activate the camera. Each should take on the image picker's image as a background once use photo is selected. However, I cannot get it to work right. I can get the first and last to use the image or all can take an image but only the first one's background changes. I'm including what I have at this time, thanks for the help.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
        self.camera1.tag = 1;
        self.camera2.tag = 1;
        self.camera3.tag = 1;

        if ([self.camera1 isEqual:self.camera1]) {          
            [self.camera1 setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.camera1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.camera1 setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.camera1.tag++;


        } else if ([self.camera2 isEqual:self.camera2]) {
            [self.camera2 setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.camera2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.camera2 setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        } else if([self.camera3 isEqual:self.camera3]) {
            [self.self.camera3 setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.self.camera3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.self.camera3 setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // not using video...don't need anything here
    }
}

-(void)useCamera:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh ok, just do:

```
[self.activeButton setImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]]
```

inside the 
`didFinishPacking` 
method. Before that though, you should add a UIButton *activeButton variable that is set every time a user taps on a button (so it can be an IBAction for example).

Also, make sure that you connected the outlets for the UIButton's if you did so using IBOutlets.

Comment: There are 3 buttons and when pressed, a button will start the camera. I'm wanting to use the photo the camera takes and make it the background image for the button that was pressed. Right now I can get it to do the background image change but not with the associated button. I've used the condition of self.button.tag == 1 or whatever. I just can't seem to show it how to say if this button pressed, take the photo it takes and make it the background image.

Comment: Oh ok, just do: [self.activeButton setImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]] inside the didFinishPacking method. Before that though, you should add a UIButton *activeButton variable that is set every time a user taps on a button (so it can be an IBAction for example).

Comment: Trying to do something like that, even added a BOOL but still can't manage to get it to work. I have the 3 buttons already on the IB and tied into the method to start the camera and the usual requirements.

Comment: have you validated that the image actually has data in it and thats its not nil? If so, then the next step would be to make sure your button variables are actually connected to what is being displayed on screen - are they IBOutlets, or did you just create them programmatically? In any case, debugging this would be extremely helpful for you and you would probably be able to find a solution very quickly

Comment: Cool. So, in the useCamera function, I create a button and assign it "sender". Then, on the active button that's got a property, set it to [NSNumber numberWithInt:button.tag]; (xcode complains about this, but it works) then in the didFinishPicking, give the buttons a tag starting at 0 and it works great. Thanks for the help Roy!! You pointed me in the right direction.